# Pinax synch db gives me no module named debug_toolbar?

Tags: python, django, eclipse, pinax

I have installed pinax, and created a project with the `pinax-admin`

After that I just wanted to synch the db with:

```
python manage.py syncdb
Error: No module named debug_toolbar
```

I am running python 2.7.3 and django 1.4.2 under win 7.

Why does this not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok guys,

I fixed the problem!
It is extremely simple:

just install the django-debug-toolbar with pip

pip install django-debug-toolbar

Comment: Nice, also same for other dependincies, either jsut pip install them or django- first